# Comma Separated User input in java

Tags: java, string, split

Below are the inputs:
Event Name, Date, No. of attendees

Catering party, 01/01/2018, 100

Wedding,24/01/2018,500

Bike Stunts show, 06/01/2018, 300

Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sc.next();
    //String line=sc.nextLine();
    String parts[] = sc.nextLine().split(", ");
    //StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,", ");
    //int j=0;
    //while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    //System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    //parts[j]=st.nextToken();
    //j++;
    //}
    //System.out.println(j);
    //String[] inputs = sc.nextLine().split(", ");`
    for (String data : parts) {
      System.out.println(data);
    }
    String name = parts[0].trim();
    String date = parts[1].trim();
    String attendee = parts[2].trim();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(attendee);
    events.add(new Event(name, date, count));
  }
}
```

Below is the Error:

3`Number of inputs`

Catering party, 01/01/2018, 100

party
01/01/2018
100

Wedding, 24/01/2018, 500

24/01/2018
500
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Main.main(Main.java:74)

I have tried both String Tokenizer and split method but as you can see in the error that I am not able to take the input in correct format. Please help me to know what is wrong in my code.

Hello Everyone! After getting stuck with sc.next() and sc.nextLine() I  have used BufferedReader to take the input. And it is working below is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {            
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line=reader.readLine();
    String parts[] = line.trim().split(",");
    for (String data : parts) {
         System.out.println(data);
    }
    name = parts[0].trim();
    date = parts[1].trim();
    attendee = parts[2].trim();
    count = Integer.parseInt(attendee);
    events.add(new Event(name, date, count));
}
```

Comment: Don't assume spaces before or after the delimiter. In one case there isn't one. Your split pattern should be `"\\s*,\\s*"`

Comment: Hi Goose, I tried your regex, but still I am getting same error.

3
Catering party, 01/01/2018, 100
 party
01/01/2018
100
Wedding,24/01/2018,500

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: I would recommend not trying to use stdin for entering multiple lines *unless* it's reading from a piped in file, as this is problematic. The regex is correct

Comment: Remove the line `sc.next();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that, from your debug logs, you're not getting the correct output even before the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is due to the `sc.next();` that you added at the beginning of the for loop. This is also the reason behind the exception in the second iteration.

##### What is actually happening

The compiler is reading the first non-space seperated integer characters through `sc.nextInt();`
Then, in the for loop, you are reading the next non-space seperated string through `sc.next();`. In your case, that's the word "Catering".

After that, the compiler is reading the rest of the line as "party, 01/01/2018, 100" and operating on it. This is why you are only getting the word "party" in the sysout rather than "Catering party".

The same happens for the next line of input, except this time the entirety of "Wedding," is considered a single `sc.next()` so you end up with "24/01/2018, 500" and an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The only reason the first line worked is because it had two words in the first argument so it didn't affect the split array size.

##### Solution

I would recommend you try to fix it yourself before reading this next part. Consider using the debugger! It's a very helpful tool.

after reading the initial number input `sc.nextInt()` you should add `sc.nextLine();` so that the compiler understands that the previous line is finished and the next read should be on a new line.

You should remove `sc.next();` as this accomplishes nothing. (I'm guessing you added this to try and solve the issue where the compiler wasn't reading the next line as mentioned previously).

Finally, I would recommend you split on `,` rather than `,`  since you're trimming the strings anyway.

##### @alankar's solution

I have used BufferedReader and now I am able to take input.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {            
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line=reader.readLine();
        String parts[] = line.trim().split(",");
        for (String data : parts) {
          System.out.println(data);
        }
        name = parts[0].trim();
        date = parts[1].trim();
        attendee = parts[2].trim();
        count = Integer.parseInt(attendee);
        events.add(new Event(name, date, count));
    }
```

Comment: When I am removing sc.next() then it is showing error at first input also. Well I have used BufferedReader and now I am able to take input.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove white spaces before splitting your input, to make sure there is no white spaces that can affect your separator, also you have to check if the user has entered three fields separated by comma. Here's an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sc.next();
    //String line=sc.nextLine();
    String parts[] = sc.nextLine().trim().split(",");
    if (parts.length != 3) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: Input must have 3 parts separated by comma");
    }
    String name = parts[0];
    String date = parts[1];
    String attendee = parts[2];
    int count = Integer.parseInt(attendee);
    events.add(new Event(name, date, count));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried this but still getting same error. I have used BufferedReader and now I am able to take input.